# php - how to get the server response header and body

Tags: php

I want to get and log every request come to my PHP file and every **response** that my PHP file outputs.

as for the request , it is easy throw the super global variables e.g `$_post['key']`, but I'm not sure how to get what my php file outputs to the client.
the only thing that I can do is to delay any `echos` in my code and build one output string like `$response` throw my php code and `echo` it at the end of the script. like :

```
$response = "";
$response .= "<html> somehtml";
//somecode if($condition){ $response .= "some html"}else{$response .= "another html"}
//more code
 $response .="</html>";
 echo $response;
 log($response); // custom function to store the response
```

but some times the php parser outputs warning and errors and other stuff than my response , beside I don't want to delay all the echos but I want to use echo throw my code for more convenience.

**Is there a way to use echos throw my code and get my *whole* response including the response headers and every thing that my php server outputs?**

Thank you.

Comment: It is normally good practice to first assemble the output from the various part of the application and then sending it to the client in one place. 
Recoding it might look dire now but it will make your program more maintainable in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and its associated methods, which will hold all output in a buffer until you want to send it.

For example:

```
ob_start();

echo 'weeee';

$output = ob_get_contents(); // get the contents from the buffer
log($output); // your custom function

ob_end_flush(); // send the output to the browser and turn off buffering
```

Comment: is `$output` now have the warnings and errors that php outputs ?

Comment: It should have everything that is normally output directly.

Comment: thaaank you, this is exactly what I was looking for . and for the response `headers` , what can I do ?

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php for that

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the automatic headers like content encoding. I'd always suggest specifying them explicitly if you need to capture them.

Comment: now I know how to get all the response headers including the automatic ones.  when I call `apache_response_headers() or headers-list()` **AT THE END OF SCRIPT**  I get all the response headers